# laravel 5 blade template for echo {{}} doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and I have a blade templated page but `{{}}` doesn't work. It skips it and doesn't echo the value in it. For example. this code

```
<h2>Delete {{$employe->fname }} Are you sure?</h2>
```

Its output:

```
Delete are you sure?
```

with out the name of employee how can I fix this

the file is saved in blade extention **delete.blade.php**

Comment: try {{{ $employe->fname }}}

Comment: the fname variable inside your array is blank cross check it by dumping the data

Comment: are sure you are passing value to view? try {{ $anyother_varibale }}

Comment: Are you sure that `$employe->fname` has a value different of empty string ??

Comment: Is it not just a typo? `employee` or `employer` rather than `employe`?

Comment: Please include the code for your controller that is returning the view in your question to make it clearer. The issue is coming from `$employe->fname` it means `fname` field is blank. Go to your database and ensure the field is not empty. Also check your model ensure the field is under `$fillable` if you have `$fillable`

Comment: there is employe->fname and it is fillable in the model

Comment: it works with other variables i think it didn't pass the variable

Comment: formatting and spelling correction

Comment: try dd($employe) and see if fname is included in there because the only reason why that value wouldn't be showing is that it doesn't exist or contains an empty/null value.

Comment: I had the same problem and it turned out that I had forgotten that I had renamed my attribute in the db so I was calling `name` when it was actually `first_name` and `last_name.`